# General way for getting all parents of specified commit

Tags: git

Is there a *general** way to get all commit's parents in a *pure*** git way?

Yep, parents of merge commit could be parsed from `git show` command, and parent of simple commit could be get with `$HASH^`-like stuff. But in my opinion it is ugly and clumsy.

So, what I want is:

```
$> git parents $NON_MERGE_COMMIT_HASH
HASH1

$> git parents $MERGE_COMMIT_HASH
HASH1
HASH2
...
```

---

*general** - single command for non-merge commits and merge commits.

*pure*** - simple git command without any parsing of output. I.e. for getting current branch name `git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD` is a pure command and `git branch` is not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git rev-parse "${HASH}"^@
```

The `^@` suffix means "all of the revision's parents" (in order).  See `git help revisions`.

Comment: Nice, this is exactly what I am looking for.

Answer (score 2):

The following seems to do the job :
`git log -1 --pretty=tformat:%P <hash>`